Transforming log-return expected shortfall to arithmetic-return expected shortfall
When deriving the Value at Risk (VaR) for log returns, one can easily transform the log-return VaR to an arithmetic-return VaR via $VaR_{arithmetic} = e^{VaR_{log}}-1$
However, how is the log-return Expected Shortfall (ES) transformed to an arithmetic-return ES? I guess the exact method would depend on the respective (assumed) distribution, right?

Correct. Effectively you are comparing $\mathbb E[R\cdot 1_{\{R\ge r\}}]$ to $\mathbb E[\log R\cdot 1_{\{R\ge r\}}]$ which will depend on the distribution of $R$.
